# Implement gRPC service to replace .NET Framework WCF service

Tags: grpc, .net-4.8

First of all, is this even possible? I know gRPC mainly works in .NET Core and I'm having issues implementing it in .NET Framework.

So far I've installed the necessary NuGet packages (Grpc.Core, GrpcCore.Api, Grpc.Net.Client, Grpc.Net.Common, and Grpc.Tools) and tried using the tutorial from https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/basics/ as a starting point.

Right now the main issue I'm running into is that my .proto file doesn't have the Build Action -> Protobuf Compiler in it's properties and is not generating the code it's supposed to when compiled.

Are there any better examples out there for me to reference?

Comment: you can try generate src from proto by command line. use [Grpc.Tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Tools/) the docs use dotnet core but i think most of the steps are same with .net framework. because .net 4.5+ is supported.

Comment: This book has a lot of resources on migrating from WCF to gRPC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/

Comment: I'd start by making sure that the .proto codegen works for you correctly when using the official examples https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/basics/ (it really should). If it does, try to see what's different in the official example vs in your test project. That should allow you to find the culprit. Without seeing the source code of your project, it's not really possible to give you a more targeted advice.